# how to see size of a window while resizing in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: gvim, window-manager, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-unity

before, i used ubuntu 10.04. i would resize gvim window and would see it's size while resizing. A small box would show rows x columns. this behavior is absent in ubuntu 11.04.
does anyone know how to turn it back on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager.
Under Utility there is a function called "Resize Info".
Activate the "Resize Info" function and choose the option to "Show resize info for all windows"